# Trigger debug session in function in a package when called by Jupyter Notebook in VS Code

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm a big fan of debugging, and writing functions. This is something that has deterred me from using Jupyter Notebook extensively.

I've recently started using VS Code, and it looks like we can nearly do that by converting the Jupyter notebook into a .py file, which can then be ran in debug mode. This is great, but a bit time consuming, and there are always little things to be tweaked in the converted file.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support

Is there a way we can link the debugger in VS Code and put a breakpoint into a .py package file containing a function, and have that triggered when we call a function from a Jupyter Notebook, all in VS Code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer on the VSCode python extension. The scenario that you were describing we don't currently support. Our debugging support for jupyter is currently limited to being able to debug #%% code regions in .py files when running them. However we do have support for directly stepping through a cell in a .ipynb file coming up in the near future. Should be coming out in some fashion in our next major release about a month from now.

Answer (score 0):

Coming in vscode v1.58 is experimental support for debugging jupyter notebooks (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_58.md#jupyter-notebook-debugging):

`"jupyter.experimental.debugging": true`

> #### Jupyter notebook debugging
>
> We have been working on supporting debugging in Jupyter notebooks, so
> that you can set breakpoints in notebook cells, execute cells
> step-by-step, and use all other VS Code debugger features. This is
> experimental, but you can try it out by setting
> `"jupyter.experimental.debugging": true`, installing version 6 of
> ipykernel in your selected kernel, then clicking the "Debug" button in
> the notebook toolbar.

[image: debugging jupyter notebooks]