# VSCode: Code Lens for Jupyter Notebook does not show debug option or "run code by line"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am still new to vscode, but I am having trouble getting some of the tools for python Jupyter notebooks to work in VSCode Version: 1.56.2 on ubuntu linux 20.04 LTS.

So according to the documentation, there are supposed to be buttons for debugging, including a button to "run code by line". This makes it easier to debug any code issues in a notebook cell. The documentation suggests the notebook interface should look like this.

[image]

The buttons in the upper left are the ones that I am interested in.

Now, when I look at my own interface, it looks like this.

[image]

So the two interfaces look very different. I am not sure if I need to change any settings in VSCode to enable these buttons. The [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support) did not mention changes to any settings.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Of interest: Debugging of jupyter notebooks https://stackoverflow.com/a/68242049/836330

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Run code by line" has not yet been implemented for the new notebooks interface that you are seeing. In the meantime, you can opt back into the old interface with "Run code by line" support by doing the following:

1. Open your user settings.json by typing Ctrl+Shift+P > "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)"
2. Add the following line to your user settings.json file:

```
"jupyter.experiments.optOutFrom": ["NativeNotebookEditor"]
```

3. If the `workbench.editorAssociations` setting is present in your settings.json file, delete it.
4. Reload VS Code for the new settings to take effect

Comment: Oh interesting. So is this the case even if I am using the VSCode Insider version?

Comment: Yes, "run code by line" for native notebooks is on our backlog and has not been implemented yet.

Comment: @joyceehl Okay, I tried the code you suggested and restarted vscode. But now I get a message "Cannot open resource with notebook editor type 'jupyter notebook', please check if you have the right extension installed or enabled." Now it is opening the notebook in the text editor, so the notebook looks like pure JSON. Do I need to install the old jupyter extension? What would the name of that extension be?

Comment: Apologies, you'll also need to delete the `workbench.editorAssociations` entry in your settings.json if it exists.

Comment: Ah yes, this seems to work now. It was that last thing, the `workbench.editorAssociations` that was the issue. Thanks so much for your help @joyceerhl. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In vscode 1.59 (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_59.md#jupyter-run-by-line)

> #### Jupyter "Run By Line"
>
> We've been working on supporting the "Run By Line" feature in Jupyter
> notebooks. This feature is essentially a simplified debug mode that
> lets you step through your cell's code line by line without any
> complex debug UI. This is still experimental, but you can try it out
> by setting `"jupyter.experimental.debugging": true`, installing
> version 6 of ipykernel in your selected kernel, then clicking the "Run
> By Line" button in the cell toolbar.

`"jupyter.experimental.debugging": true`

---

Of interest

> We have been working on supporting debugging in Jupyter notebooks, so
> that you can set breakpoints in notebook cells, execute cells
> step-by-step, and use all other VS Code debugger features. This is
> experimental, but you can try it out by setting
> `"jupyter.experimental.debugging": true`, installing version 6 of
> ipykernel in your selected kernel, then clicking the "Debug" button in
> the notebook toolbar.

in vscode v.158, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_58.md#jupyter-notebook-debugging

Comment: for some reason this is not working. changed the settings.json, reloaded vscode. ipykernel version is 6.0.3. Am I missing anything

Answer (score 1):

Make a debug point and just press F10 ; Debug will started automatically